# How to update multi row in sql with option tag

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to update multi row in mysql table with one submit while teacher can give every student the grade and save all row at once

Can anyone help with the right way?

this code is record the last row only

```
<form class="multisteps-form__form clearfix" action="?do=Update" method="post" id="wizard">
                        <div class="multisteps-form__panel js-active" data-animation="slideVert">
                          <?php
                   $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM student  ");
                   $stmt->execute();
                   $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
                     foreach($rows as $row) { 
                          $id = $row['id'];
                         $math_activity = $row['math_activity'];
                         $math_attendance = $row['math_attendance'];
                          $math_evaluation = $row['math_evaluation'];
                        ?>             
                    <input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="<?php echo $id ?>" />
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <div class="badge-selection">
                                        <h3><?php echo $row['student_name']; ?></h3></div></div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                            <div class="n-select-option">
                                                <select name="math_activity">
                                                    <option>Activity</option>
                                                    <option  name="2" value="25">25</option>
                                                    <option  name="3" value="50">50</option>
                                                </select></div></div>
                                       <div class="col-md-3">
                                            <div class="n-select-option">
                                                <select name="math_attendance">
                                                    <option>Attendance</option>
                                                    <option  name="2" value="25">25</option>
                                                    <option  name="3" value="50">50</option>
                                                </select></div></div>
                                        <div class="col-md-3">
                                            <div class="n-select-option">
                                                <select name="math_evaluation">
                                                    <option>Evaluation</option>
                                                    <option  name="2" value="25">25</option>
                                                    <option  name="3" value="50">50</option>
                                                </select></div></div></div>
                                    <?php } ?>
                                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                    <input  type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" />
                </div></div></div></div></div></div></form>
                    <?php
                    $count=count(array($_POST["id"]));
                    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
                    $do = isset($_GET['do']) ? $_GET['do'] : 'Manage';
                    if ($do == 'Update'){
            $id         = $_POST['id'];
            $math_activity          = $_POST['math_activity'];
            $math_attendance        = $_POST['math_attendance'];
            $math_evaluation    = $_POST['math_evaluation'];
    $stmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE student SET math_activity[$i] = ?, math_attendance[$i] = ?, math_evaluation[$i] = ?  WHERE id[$i] = ?");
            $stmt->execute(array($math_evaluation, $math_attendance, $math_activity, $id));
    }}?>
```

Comment: A column called math_activity in a table called student is highly indicative of poor schema design

Answer (score 0):

As I assume, your tableHeaders are fix, and not supposed to change?

Table Student:

```
math_activity  |  math_attendance   |   math_evaluation    <- tableHead
1                   6436                  3445
2                    345                    335            <-inserted rows

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE student SET math_activity = ?, math_attendance = ?, math_evaluation = ? WHERE id = ?")
        
        foreach($rows as $row => $value){
        
          $stmt->bind_param("iiii", $math_activity[$row], $math_attendance[$row], $math_evaluation[$row], $id[$row]);    //watch ou Datatypes ("iiii" are correct)
          $stmt->execute();
    }
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp